Gradle sync failled in Android studio
I recently install Android studio(2024.1.00) application for develop app but when open the app they tell me 'design editor is unavailable until after a successful project sync in'. I had download jdk 22 and gradle 8.9 versions. And i already set path of gradle and java in system.
Who know solution about error,. Share me
When I was open. The xml. File then show this type of error and and design editor not show

Android Studio already includes the correct JDK version (AFAIK JDK 17). JDK 22 is not yet supported and can be the root cause of your problems. But as you forgot to include the error message as text into your question it is unknown what causes your problems.
